# Exclude a specific Error from being logged?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I want to exclude the following error from being logged. What do I have to set on my Config.groovy?

```
2013-08-28 15:10:13,501 [http-nio-8080-exec-85] ERROR websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor  - 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request object no longer valid. This object has been cancelled
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.getRequest(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:447)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.getRequest(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:467)
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol.onMessage(SimpleHttpProtocol.java:95)
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.invokeWebSocketProtocol(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:293)
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatchReader(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:627)
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.invokeWebSocketProtocol(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:402)
    at org.atmosphere.container.TomcatWebSocketHandler.onTextData(TomcatWebSocketHandler.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can easily suppress just that one specific error, but you could suppress all ERROR level log messages for that particular class by putting

```
fatal 'org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor'
```

inside your log4j closure.

Comment: What does fatal means?

Comment: @confile it's the highest log level, above error. So that statement is telling log4j to only log messages at the "fatal" level or higher (though in this case there is no higher level) and ignore lower levels. If you used `error` it would log error and fatal messages, `warn` would log warn, error and fatal, etc.